# Syncronization software with smart update

Tags: windows, backup, file-synchronization

I'm looking for a Windows software that synchronizes files between different drives but analysing for existing files so it doesn't need to copy the file again.

Is there a software that analyses the chosen directory and if the source file is already in the destination directory but in a different path it simply moves the file to the correct directory (in the destination drive) and not copy from source drive to the destination drive?

Comment: Related question: [Auto sync libraries on two machines without storing data with 3rd party](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/11242/2210)

Comment: @CristianCiupitu it's not a related question. I'm looking for a local machine software between two drives, not a network solution for diferent machines.

Comment: Some version control systems detect movement of files, but using that might be overkill for you.

Comment: I'm a programmer so I'm used to version control. But that's like saying to install Visual Studio just to edit a text file.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [AllWay Sync](http://allwaysync.com/)

It's free for personal use, and it compares 2 folders to achieve sync. You can start a compare job anytime, or schedule it as you wish.

It doesn't "move" the file if it simply changed location, but this looks like an impossible task, you would have to compare all file of the first folder to all the files of the second one...

Comment: Free to use up to a monthly data limit (which I can't remember, but I do remember that it was nowhere near enough for me|)

Answer (score 1):

I did a similar search a few weeks ago (G.I.Y.F) and came up with http://www.freefilesync.org/

It is super efficient and will keep two directories in absolute synch, whether local or networked.

> Key Features
>
> ```
> Detect moved and renamed files and folders
> Copy locked files (Volume Shadow Copy Service)
> Detect conflicts and propagate deletions
> Binary file comparison
> Configure handling of Symbolic Links
> Automate sync as a batch job
> Process multiple folder pairs
> Comprehensive and detailed error reporting
> Copy NTFS extended attributes (compressed, encrypted, sparse)
> Copy NTFS security permissions
> Support long file paths with more than 260 characters
> Fail-safe file copy
> Cross-platform: Windows, Linux, Mac OS X
> Expand environment variables like %USERPROFILE%
> Access variable drive letters by volume name (USB sticks)
> Native 64-bit support
> Keep versions of deleted/updated files
> Prevent disc space bottlenecks via optimal sync sequence
> Full Unicode support
> Highly optimized runtime performance
> Include/exclude files via filter
> FreeFileSync portable and local installation available
> Handle daylight saving time changes on FAT/FAT32
> Use macros %time%, %date%, et al. for recurring backups
> Case-sensitive synchronization
> Built-in locking: serialize multiple jobs running against the same network share
> ```

Answer (score 1):

rsync is available for Windows as [cwRsync](https://www.itefix.net/cwrsync). Command line utility that can do pretty much anything you want in terms of syncing data between drives.

NOT the most intuitive thing to use, but it works great, and it's generally pretty quick, as it tries really hard to not move data it doesn't have to.